# Errors using F__AnonymousType in C#

Tags: c#, anonymous-class

I spent hours trying to resolve compilation issues related to `f__AnonymousType`. Seems to gets a lot of errors regarding expressions needing directives but not sure exactly what to do.

```
public static void ChangeSerialNumber(char volume, uint newSerial)
{
    var source = new <>f__AnonymousType0<string, int, int>[]
    {
        new
        {
            Name = "FAT32",
            NameOffs = 82,
            SerialOffs = 67
        },
        new
        {
            Name = "FAT",
            NameOffs = 54,
            SerialOffs = 39
        },
        new
        {
            Name = "NTFS",
            NameOffs = 3,
            SerialOffs = 72
        }
    };

    using (Helpers.Disk disk = new Helpers.Disk(volume))
    {
        byte[] sector = new byte[512];
        disk.ReadSector(0U, sector);
        var <>f__AnonymousType = source.FirstOrDefault(f => Helpers.Strncmp(f.Name, sector, f.NameOffs));
        if (<>f__AnonymousType == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This file system is not supported");
        }

        uint num = newSerial;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 4)
        {
            sector[<>f__AnonymousType.SerialOffs + i] = (byte)(num & 255U);
            i++;
            num >>= 8;
        }
        disk.WriteSector(0U, sector);
    }
}
```

This is used for USB Stick Refurbishments in order as part of the software to secure wipe, we would like to change the serial numbers of the drive (in effect spoof them) in case of a chargeback we can match the drive they return to make sure its the one we sent out.

Comment: Can you share the error messages?

Comment: You've decompiled some compiler-generated code. Such code uses names, such as this, that *aren't legal C#*. It does this to avoid naming collisions. You need to pick different names.

Comment: `var source = new[] { new { ... }, ... }`. `<>f__AnonymousType0` is a compiler-generated type, which you can't refer to directly

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/10da32151f3c3067a4ea06ef4c303f62.png

Comment: This looks like ofbsuscated and decompiled code. We shouldn't be helping with possible illegal action.

Comment: @Sinatr What makes you think it's been obfuscated?

Comment: some docs about anonymous in c# https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-csharp-3-0-features-4-anonymous-type

Comment: @BrendanBroadhead You'll also have to change the name of the `<>f__AnonymousType` variable as well, of course

Comment: @Sinatr - obfuscated but with `source` and `sector` local variable names making sense? Unlikely.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Decompiled code doesn't have local variable names available anyway (they're not preserved in IL), so those names have been generated by the decompiler

Comment: @Sinatr its not Obfusicated code, there is nothing illegal with it was acquired as part of a public git for USB Drive Flashing, I just could not get it to work personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point about anonymous type, is that you don't have to give them a name, the compiler will do it for you.

`<>f__AnonymousType0` is not a valid name in user code, but looks like the name generated by the compiler. You can't use it.

Just use [anonymous syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) :

```
public static void ChangeSerialNumber(char volume, uint newSerial)
{
    var sources = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            Name = "FAT32",
            NameOffs = 82,
            SerialOffs = 67
        },
        new
        {
            Name = "FAT",
            NameOffs = 54,
            SerialOffs = 39
        },
        new
        {
            Name = "NTFS",
            NameOffs = 3,
            SerialOffs = 72
        }
    };

    using (Helpers.Disk disk = new Helpers.Disk(volume))
    {
        byte[] sector = new byte[512];
        disk.ReadSector(0U, sector);

        var source = sources.FirstOrDefault(f => Helpers.Strncmp(f.Name, sector, f.NameOffs));
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This file system is not supported");
        }

        var num = newSerial;
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 4)
        {
            sector[source.SerialOffs + i] = (byte) (num & 255U);
            i++;
            num >>= 8;
        }

        disk.WriteSector(0U, sector);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrendanBroadhead, Out of curiosity how did you manage to have `<>f__AnonymousType0` written in your code ? Can you share the URL of the *public git* you speak about earlier ?